# Get Primary Key column values after bulk insertion using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

Can anyone help me how to get the column values of a Primary Key column after bulk insertion?

I am using SqlBulkCopy to insert multiple rows at a time into table(say Table 1). I need the ids of a column MsgId(PK) from Table 1 once the rows get inserted. I need to use these ids which is the foreign key in another table Table 2

Here is my code,

```
        DataTable dtMessageDetails = new DataTable("Message Details");
        SqlBulkCopy copier = new SqlBulkCopy(Connectionstring);
        copier.DestinationTableName = "Table 1";
        copier.WriteToServer(dtMessageDetails);
```

Comment: Looks like there's a `SqlRowsCopied` event, but it's designed for UI interaction so I'm not sure how reliable it is or how it would perform getting called every row.  Otherwise, you could specify ID in the insert, but that's a bit ugly.

Comment: How's built your PK? Is it auto-generated in some way?

Comment: Yes it is an identity column and is auto-generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lock the table before you insert your bulk. You know the number of rows and if you select the last id, knowing the total number of elements, then you will know their IDs.

Comment: What if you are concurrently inserting?

Comment: Well, that's why we lock the table in the first place, isn't that?

Comment: @LajosArpad after locking the table, when should we have to take the last id of the table. Last id of the table should be taken before inserting the bulk or after inserting it? Also could you please explain when does the table lock happens or occurs?